# In COD Ghosts, do I lose progress on my operations if I get new operations before completing the old ones?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I have a bunch of operations that I'm working on but i probably won't finish them before the timer runs out and i get new operations.  Will I lose the progress I made?  Is there a way to prevent losing the operations I'm working on?

Answer (score 1):

You don't lose any progress on your operations when they swap out.

There are five groups of operations and you can tag one in each group, which will lock it, preventing it from changing.